# Odoo 10 + Odoo 8. Y ya no arranca ninguno

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp

Tenía un Odoo 10 corriendo sin problemas. Necesitaba un entorno del 8. Después de clonar, ejecutando el requirements empezó a dar problemas. Uno de ellos, que le faltaba lber.h. Una solución que encontré por ahí -de entre muchas- incluía ejecutar esto:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
```

Durante su ejecución vi que desinstalaba varias cosas, ya no recuerdo cuáles.

Después los problemas de requirements se multiplicaron. No encontraba el /METADATA de varias librerías. Extrañamente, porque creaba una carpeta dentro de otra con el mismo nombre. Es decir, si no encontraba *~/home/user.../libreríaX/METADATA* resulta que había creado *libreríaX/libreríaX/METADATA* junto con varios archivos más. Si los sacaba "a capón" al directorio superior ya no daba error, pero en un minuto sobreescribía y volvía a dejarlo como antes, con lo que se repetía el error.

Además, ahora intento volver a arrancar el Odoo 10 y ya no chuta nada. Me da lo siguiente:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo-bin --config=/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo.conf --dev=all --test-enable --save
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2171, in declare_namespace
    declare_namespace(parent)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2187, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2120, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 243, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    import modules
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 13, in <module>
    import odoo.osv as osv
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/osv/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import osv
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/osv/osv.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import except_orm
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tools.func import frame_codeinfo
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from convert import *
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .translate import _
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 27, in <module>
    from odoo import sql_db, SUPERUSER_ID
  File "/home/user/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 18, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Creo que resulta obvio que soy muy novato, así que me disculpo por anticipado por errores, tonterías y reiteraciones. Prometo que he hecho múltiples búsquedas antes de escribir. Y sospecho que he jodido directamente la instalación de Python.

Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida.

Comment: Yo en tu lugar intentaría usar `virtualenv` para crear dos carpetas, una para odoo8 y otra para odoo10. Después instalaría por separado en cada una de ellas (con `pip install`) las dependencias necesarias a cada caso. Y después ejecutaría los scripts activando uno u otro de esos entornos. Presupongo que sabes activarlos. Mira [aqui](http://www.pythondiario.com/2016/04/instalar-y-utilizar-virtualenv-virtual.html) por ejemplo si no.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, solucionado (parece) tras formateo y clonado de varias versiones de Odoo. En el caso de la 8, donde empezaron los problemas, volvió a aparecer el error con psycopg2. Aparentemente se ha solucionado "por las bravas":

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo versiones diferentes conviviendo, lo que yo hago es instalar la versión mas reciente via apt-get install y la otra bajo el código y la corro desde una carpeta, teniendo todas las dependencias corren muy bien

Saludo